# How can I setup social providers programatically in firebase auth with multi-tanancy

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, multi-tenant

**Context**

I have a white label application with multiples partners and each partner can create multiples "web apps". Each web app has your own "auth database". Ex: A partner created a web app A and a web app B. If his user creates an account in web app A, he can't login into web app B, just in web app A.

**How I will do that**

I am using firebase authentication. And I will do that using multi-tenancy (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart). Each partner will have a firebase project associated with his account and each web app will be associated with a a sub-project (tenant). Each tenant will need to setup many social login providers, like facebook and google.

**The Problem**

I can setup the social provider via console. But I can't find how can I do that programatically using API. I just found how can I setup social providers via api without using tenant (https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/provisioning/configure-oauth)

It is possible to setup social providers with multi-tenancy programatically using API?

Answer (score 1):

I believe one way would be using the Identity Platform API:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/create

You just find the parameters for the Supported IDP you're adding.

The list of supported IDPs you can find here:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/defaultSupportedIdps/list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add the Google provider in one of my projects in Identity Platform (which shares the same APIs as Firebase I believe).

1. List the default supported identity providers for Identity Platform.

You can find the reference here:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/defaultSupportedIdps/list

It should return all the IDs of the possible identity providers. Here is the result I got when calling it with my Ruby code.

```rb
{:idp_id=>"apple.com"}
{:idp_id=>"facebook.com"}
{:idp_id=>"gc.apple.com"}
{:idp_id=>"github.com"}
{:idp_id=>"google.com"}
{:idp_id=>"linkedin.com"}
{:idp_id=>"microsoft.com"}
{:idp_id=>"playgames.google.com"}
{:idp_id=>"twitter.com"}
{:idp_id=>"yahoo.com"}
```

2. Create an identity provider configuration for your tenant.

You can find the reference here:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/create

You should provide the following fields in the [request body](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs):

- `name`: corresponds to one of the `idp_id` in step 1
- `client_id`: the client ID of your OAuth application
- `client_secret`: the client secret of your OAuth application
- `enabled`: `true` if you want to enable the provider

That is it. You should be able to see the newly created provider in your tenant's `Providers` tab.

[image: google cloud platform - identity platform]

You can find an implementation of one Google Identity Platform API wrapper in Ruby that I used in one of my projects.

https://gist.github.com/tonystrawberry/41910f127e49dc80feedc5ec76aeb4cc